# What program makes clean plain SVG files from Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I have SVG images with Inkscape attributes that fail epubcheck and Google validation.

When I try to save them as plain SVG, the invalid "inkscape:XXX:" elements remain.

What program on what platform can load in the Inkscape SVG and save them as clean plain SVG?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you reported this to Inkscape?

Comment: Heavily Related: [Can I reduce the file size of an SVG to be closer to its JPEG equivalent?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50837/can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-an-svg-to-be-closer-to-its-jpeg-equivalent/)

Answer (score 6):

Try this [script](http://jsfiddle.net/alexanderby/31nmr8f7/). Open file and then press "Save".

Comment: Thank you, I think it worked.  Does it alter the geometry?

Comment: The program only removes inkscape:***, sodipodi:***, rdf:***, cc:*** and dc:*** elements and attributes and doesn't touch the SVG elements and attributes. But you may open the file (e.g. in browser) and check that it is displayed correctly. Later I will make some more convenient utility.